# Snowflake-Jitterbit Connector Error: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: No active warehouse selected in the current session

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jitterbit

I am receiving the below error while trying to connect to Snowflake via Jitterbit cloud studio:

Error

> Error Code: `snowflake07`

Stacktrace:

```
Error executing get activity. ,Stack Trace: org.jitterbit.connector.sdk.exceptions.ActivityExecutionException: Error executing get activity.
at org.jitterbit.connector.snowflake.activities.GetActivity.execute(GetActivity.java:94)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.


The integration is configured in Jitterbit but not sure what setting I need to update in Snowflake to make a GET call.
Or is there a way to use the "USE WAREHOUSE" command in Jitterbit before connecting to Snowflake?
```

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake requires "compute" resources to run queries, and these compute resources are called warehouses.  Most client tools let you set login/configuration parameters and this is where they would set their warehouse for compute.

If Jitterbit does not allow this (though I think it's JDBC, so it should), perhaps you can simply set a default compute Warehouse for the user who is logging in, to do so you issue a ALTER USER command, such as the following:

```
ALTER USER your_user_id_here SET DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE = your_warehouse_name;
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

Setting the default warehouse for the user will most likely allow you to get past your initial connection issue.